# How to conform an Array to 'Identifiable'

Tags: arrays, swift, list, swiftui, identifiable

I'm confused about how Identifiable arrays work. For instance, I have the following array returned as a response to a function:

```
Optional (["Jane", "John", "Eric", "Erika", "Motto"])
```

Now, I want to show this as a list but we know that list items need to conform to Identifiable. How can I conform an array like this to 'Identifiable'? I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68061637/conforming-an-array-to-identifiable-in-swiftui) but it didn't seem to help a lot.

Comment: What you've printed here isn't an Array. It's an Optional. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Note that the array doesn't need to conform to Identifiable -- the *elements* of the array do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it. simple doing the following should do the job:

```
    @State private var options: [String] = []
    // then use this

          ForEach(options, id:\.self){ option in
            Text(option)
```

Comment: Do be careful with this. It requires that no two elements in `options` be the same value. But if you can ensure that's true, it's fine.

Comment: Or use indices instead, `ForEach(options.indices, id:\.self) { index in Text(options[index] }`